# Add a javascript result to an image url

Tags: javascript, html, css

So what im trying to do is query a Minecraft server with javascript, and with the response i get back with the api, i want to grab the .playerlist and put the response in this url (https://cravatar.eu/avatar/ {name} /100.png) for each person connected

If someone knows a better way to achieve this, i would very much appreciate your input!

Im also pretty new to javascript, so not fully know what im doing :/

Heres the HTML that i have (i know it may be messy, its also not fully my code)

```
<div class="card"> <div class="icon"><img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/minecraft-1.svg"></div><div class="header">
  <div class="image"> <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/lmn/image/upload/e_sharpen:100/f_auto,fl_lossy,q_auto/v1/gameskinnyc/u/n/t/untitled-a5150.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
 
  <h2>Server Status</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="rest">Loading...</div>
  <img src="https://cravatar.eu/avatar/" $face "/>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript

```
//Query api at this address

var url = "https://api.minetools.eu/query/play.aydaacraft.online/25565";

$.getJSON(url, function(r) {
    //data is the JSON string
 if(r.error){
    $('#rest').html('Server Offline.');
   return false;
 } 
var p1 = '';
 if(r.Players > 0 ){ p1 = '<br>'+r.Playerlist;  } 

// Text to display below
  $('#rest').html('Total Online: '+r.Players+p1);

// Trying to add playerlist to html url
  $('#face').html+p1;
});
```

Comment: what happens with the current code you have? it is not working? is there an error or ?

Comment: The url responds with "timed-out", it's hard to help you when we can't see the JSON schematic.

Comment: @ConnorSimpson It shouldnt be anymore, looks like i just overloaded the service before...

Comment: @kimcodes The code at the moment just says how many is online and then lists them as text.. But i want to display their avatar instead of the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've pasted jQuery code, I'll submit my answer in jQuery. However, I do recommend you learn primitive JavaScript and not focus your attention just on jQuery... [it's become something of a meme on StackOverflow](https://external-preview.redd.it/TPdvnT2J6FMhVPgwGMyuQ7GZaoVCpTIVEpU2j_bN9XY.gif?format=mp4&s=54a0a0c42880f7001257d64ef82e0351eb0cb56f).

Starting off, you really should be wrapping your code in `$(document).ready` this'll only run the code when the page has loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
   // The document is ready, let's run some code!
});
```

Then add your AJAX request as normal inside this bracket.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

   let url = "https://api.minetools.eu/query/play.aydaacraft.online/25565";
   $.getJSON(url, response => {
     
   });

});
```

Okay, whilst writing this, I checked the URL provided by OP and saw that it was timing out so I've grabbed a sample response from the [Minetools' documentation](https://api.minetools.eu/query/).

```json
{
  "MaxPlayers": 200,
  "Motd": "A Minecraft Server",
  "Playerlist": [
     "Connor",
     "Kamil",
     "David"
  ],
  "Players": 3,
  "Plugins": [],
  "Software": "CraftBukkit on Bukkit 1.8.8-R0.2-SNAPSHOT",
  "Version": "1.8.8",
  "status": "OK"
}
```

So in your JSON response, you can see that `Playerlist` is a `array` which can contain multiple things in one variable. You can also `iterate` through an `array`, which is what we'll be doing to build the image URLs.

We iterate through an array using `forEach`.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

   let url = "https://api.minetools.eu/query/play.aydaacraft.online/25565";
   $.getJSON(url, response => {
      response.Playerlist.forEach(playerName => {
         console.log(playerName);
      });
   });

});
//Console:
//Connor
//Kamil
//David
```

Now that we're iterating through the player list we can start assembling the URLs for these images and adding them to your document's body.

I've cleaned up your HTML, take note of the new `div#user-images` I've added. This'll be the place where jQuery will add your images from the `forEach` loop.

```html
<div class="card"> 
    <div class="icon">
        <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/minecraft-1.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/lmn/image/upload/e_sharpen:100/f_auto,fl_lossy,q_auto/v1/gameskinnyc/u/n/t/untitled-a5150.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>

        <h2>Server Status</h2>
        
    </div>
    
    <!-- This div tag will need to hide when there is no error, or say when there is. -->
    <div id="rest">Loading...</div>
    
    <!-- The user images will be added inside this div. -->
    <div id="user-images"></div>
</div>
```

Now we have our HTML ready we can start using the jQuery function `appendTo` to add elements into our `div#user-images`.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

   let url = "https://api.minetools.eu/query/play.aydaacraft.online/25565";
   $.getJSON(url, response => {
      response.Playerlist.forEach(playerName => {
         $(`<img src="https://cravatar.eu/avatar/${playerName}" />`).appendTo("#user-images");
      });
   });

});
```

Your `div#user-images` should start filling up with the images of players from the `Playerlist` array.

I noticed you added a simple way of showing whether or not there's an error with the API. We can interact with `div#rest` to show/hide or change text depending on the success of the response.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

   let url = "https://api.minetools.eu/query/play.aydaacraft.online/25565";
   $.getJSON(url, response => {
      if(response.error){
         $("#rest").html("The server is offline!");
      }else{
         //There is no error, hide the div#rest
         $("#rest").hide();
    
         response.Playerlist.forEach(playerName => {
            $(`<img src="https://cravatar.eu/avatar/${playerName}" />`).appendTo("#user-images");
         });
      }
   });

});
```

And that's it really. I hope this gives you some understanding of arrays, and iterating through them, as well as some DOM functions from jQuery.

Comment: Thank you heaps for not only answering my question but also for teaching me a little bit more! I’m hoping I can improve my skills a little bit more from you today :)